# How to check if a value exists in either of two columns and get average of another column sql(bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have data in the below format, basically pairwise distance score of two string names:

**Table A**

```
name1   name2    score    
xxx     xxa      0.4    
xxb     xxc      0.2     
xxd     xxa      0.6  
xxa     zzz      0.8
```

I need the output in below format for e.g. for each name present in either in name1 or name2, taking the average of score by unique name in two columns. In the above table, xxa has score in 3 rows, so we take average and get a single score of 0.6

**Output Table**

name score

```
xxx  0.4    
xxa  0.6    
xxb  0.2    
xxc  0.2    
zzz  0.8
```

I am using the below query to get the result, it works for small data in bigquery, but my input table tableA is 900Million in size and the query just doesn't finish

```
with all_names as (
select distinct name1 as name from 
tableA
union distinct 
select distinct name2 as name from 
tableA )

select name,avg(score) as avg_score
from tableA as a, all_names as b
where (b.name=a.name1 or b.name=a.name2)
group by 1
```

Is there any better efficient way to perform this operation?

Comment: In your expected output, any reason to miss **xxd** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try below query:

```sql
SELECT name, ROUND(AVG(score), 1) avg 
  FROM tableA, UNNEST([name1, name2]) name
 GROUP BY 1;

+------+-----+
| name | avg |
+------+-----+
| xxa  | 0.6 |
| xxb  | 0.2 |
| xxc  | 0.2 |
| xxd  | 0.6 |
| xxx  | 0.4 |
| zzz  | 0.8 |
+------+-----+
```

Or, if you prefer to use **UNION**,

```sql
SELECT name, ROUND(AVG(score), 1) avg 
  FROM (
    SELECT name1 AS name, score FROM tableA
     UNION ALL
    SELECT name2 AS name, score FROM tableA
  )
 GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: @nbk, you mean **UNION** query ? if so, I did and got same result as first one.  Do you notice something wrong with it?

Comment: no sorrymay bad

Comment: @nbk, it's  ok. thanks for carefully reviewing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider

```
select name, avg(score) avg_score
from your_table
unpivot(name for col in (name1, name2))
group by name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]